# How to prevent UITableViewCell backgroundView from stretching

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'm attempting to add a background image to a UITableViewCell so that each cell can have some spacing at the bottom.

I'm setting the cell's backgroundView property like this:

```
 [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell"]]];
```

The "cell" image is 20px taller than the actual heigh of the UITableViewCell, this is on purpose so that my cells can have some spacing at the bottom. Only problem is, the "cell" image will get stretched all the way down the cell's contentView.

Is there a way for me to prevent the cell from stretching the backgroundView all the way down?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [contentMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) property of UIView. If the height of your background image is smaller than the height of the cell and you want the image to "stick to the top" try setting

```
cell.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
```

Look at the "Content Modes" section on [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html) for more information. It mentions...

> "By default, the contentMode property for most views is set to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, which causes the view’s contents to be scaled to fit the new frame size."

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The `UIImageView` only obeys the value of `contentMode`, which is by default `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1) Make your image bigger manually, filling it with transparent space in the gaps. (Easier solution).

2) Add another UIView inside your UITableViewCell, make it as big as the image. Add your text label (if any) inside this view.